# Bootstrap 4 in Visual Studio asp.net full framework project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Is there a way to use bootstrap 4 in a file->new project and targeting the full .net framework for a web project? Currently it looks like it is using bootstrap 3. Would be nice if there was a new project template using bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a new project template for Bootstrap 4 unless you find a 3rd party template or package to use.

However, you can create a project using the Bootstrap 3 template and [upgrade it to Bootstrap 4](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/bootstrap-asp-net-core-mvc) via the Package manager. If you do this to begin with, you'll only have to update a few of the default pages to work with Bootstrap 4. If you're using MVC, you'll also need to [update the CodeTemplates to use Bootstrap 4 instead of 3](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/create-custom-scaffold-templates-asp-net-mvc/) if you plan to use scaffolding. I've done this in multiple projects and have a fully functioning scaffolding system using Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Thank you! In the provided link it uses MVC as an example however the same logic applies to webforms as well right?

Comment: Yes, it applies to both. I use both webforms and MVC in my project with no issue.

Comment: If I answered your question, please consider choosing my answer as "Best Answer". Thanks!